# How do Transfer Agents/Share Registrars get the names of beneficiary shareholders

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, limited-liability-company

If Transfer Agents need the names of the beneficiary share holders (e.g. for corporate actions / book closure), how do they get this data - from the stock exchange (or) Central Custodian (or) bank custodians/brokers who are depositary agents? Do they have to pay a fees for this? I am particularly interested in Hong Kong and Singapore market practices in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

In the United States, the stock certificate is updated to include beneficiary information.  I expect it to be similar with other markets.

TOD (Transfer on Death) From: http://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/free-books/avoid-probate-book/chapter3-2.html *(emphasis added)*

> If you have a brokerage account, contact the broker for instructions.
>   Most likely, the broker will send you a form on which you’ll name
>   beneficiaries to inherit your account. From then on, the account will
>   be listed in your name, with the beneficiary’s name after it, like
>   this: “Evelyn M. Meyers, TOD Jason Meyers.”
>
> **If you have the actual stock certificates or bonds in your possession
>   (most people don’t), you must get new certificates issued**, showing
>   that you now own the stock in beneficiary form. Ask your broker for
>   help; if that doesn’t work, contact the transfer agent for the stock.
>   You can get the address from your broker or the investor relations
>   office of the corporation. The transfer agent will probably have you
>   send in the certificates, a form called a stock or bond power (some
>   stock certificates have the power printed on the back), and a letter
>   explaining what you want to do.